# Activate user form email in php

Tags: php, email, authentication, registration

I am trying to make registration page for employees. 
Once Employee register activation link should send to admin email and once admin click on that link Employee should get activated. and message should send to employee email that he can now login to his account... So far i write a code to store employee details in the database, and to send message in admin email heirs my code.

```
<?php  

#database coding
if(!empty($_POST['txtfstname']) && !empty($_POST['txtlstname']) &&     !empty($_POST['txtemail']) && !empty($_POST['txtempno']))  
        {
    $con=mysqli_connect("servername","username",'password',"database");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }


    // escape variables for security
    $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['txtfstname']);
    $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['txtlstname']);
        $empno = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['txtempno']);
            $pass = substr(hash('sha256', mt_rand()), 0, 50);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['txtemail']);
            $email_code = md5($_POST['txtfstname'] + microtime());
            if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
                                {  

                                }
            else
                {
             $sql="INSERT INTO empreg (first_name, last_name, email, emp_no, password, email_code)
             VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname','$email','$empno','$pass','$email_code')";

             if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
               {
              die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
               }
                echo "1 record added";
       }
mysqli_close($con);



#email Coding
# It's best to just make sure each element isn't empty, using the empty() function.  
# Note that if a field is not set, it is NULL, which is consdered empty, so there  
# is no need to use the isset() function as well. 


            $firstname = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtfstname']))); 
            $lastname = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtlstname']))); 
            $email = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtemail'])));
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
                            if(!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email))  
                    {   
                    # Return Error - Invalid Email 
                    $msg = 'The email you have entered is invalid, please try again.';  
                    } 
                else 
                                {  
                # Sending the Email Message 
                # I moved this into the else clause. By putting it outside it was getting 
                # sent even if the email was invalid, which isn't exactly a good idea :)
                $to = 'adminemail@something.com'; // Send email to receipient
                $subject = 'Employee Registration'; // Give the email a subject
 $message = 'From: ' . $firstname . "\r\r\n" . $lastname . "\r\r\r\n" . 'IP Address: ' . $ip; // Our message above including who sent it

$message_body .= "Please click on link to activate Employee \n\n email=$email   $email_code ";


                # Here I am capturing the return value of the mail() function so that I
                # can check if it was actually successful. Just because the function is
                # executed does not mean the email was sent. The return value tells us
                # whether it was or not.
                $success = mail($to,$subject,$message_body); // Send our email
                if($success) 
                    {
                        # The email was sent successfully!
                        $msg = 'Thank you for your message.';
                    }
                else 
                    {
                        # Email failed to send.
                        $msg = 'An error occured. The mail could not be sent.';
                    }
            }
        }

    else if (!isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            # If the form hasn't been submitted yet, then do nothing. Do not prompt to enter a name just yet.
        }
    # One of the fields was empty. This finds out which one and creates a message
    # to indicate which it was.
    else
        {
            $msg = "*";
            if(empty($_POST['txtfstname'])) 
            {
                $msg .= "Please enter your first name";
            }
            elseif(empty($_POST['txtlstname']))
            {
                $msg .= "Please enter your last name";
            }
            elseif(empty($_POST['txtemail'])) 
            {
                $msg .= "Please enter your email";
            } 
            else 
            {
                $msg .= "Please enter your employee number";
            }
        }



?>

<form id="contact" class="form" action="" method="post" name="contact"><strong>Employee  Registration</strong>
<em>Please enter the following information and submit. Once the administrator approves your registration, you will receive a confirmation email with login details.</em>
<p><?php echo $msg ?></p>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>First Name:</td>
<td><input id="name" class="required" name="txtfstname" type="text" value="<?php echo    $_POST['txtfstname']; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name:</td>
<td><input id="name" class="required" name="txtlstname" type="text" value="<?php echo  $_POST['txtlstname']; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email:</td>
<td><input id="name" class="required" name="txtemail" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['txtemail']; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Employee No:</td>
<td><input id="name" class="required" name="txtempno" type="text" value="<?php echo    $_POST['txtempno']; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

here is my database columns.

ID ,
first_name,
last_name,
email,
emp_no,
password,
status,
email_code

now i want few things heir which i am not able to figure it out
        1. how to update status form 0 to 1 when admin click activation link in email
        2. how to send email to employees that he is activated and now can login to his account when admin activate employee. 
        3. when employee register mail send to admin is getting inside SPAM folder. but i want it inside Inbox. what to do for that. 
Any help is appreciable thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so, basically click the link, redirect this way:

The `$user` variable must be having the username of the user who is getting their account activated.

```
<a href="activate.php?user=<?php echo $user; ?>">Activate</a>
```

So, in the activate.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['user']) && strlen($_GET['user']) > 0) {
// Update the users activated status from 0 to 1 by running a query.
// Mail to the employee of his account activation
} else {
// No user selected.
}
```

To resolve the issue of the Mail being received in Spam folder, save the email to your contacts/unblock that email and it will be received in the Inbox.

Comment: $email = $_GET['email']; i write this code in my activation page but it is not reading email.. ? please help.

Comment: Well, on the <a href="activate.php?email=<?php echo $email; ?>"></a>

Make sure that there is already a variable called $email which is storing the email of the user, I suggest setting $_SESSION['email'] would be good when logging in.

Answer (score -1):

I am not really experienced in PHP, but I have sent emails before using the mail() function.
To learn more about these you can look on:

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp)

[Php Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

I hope this helps you :)